# Why do you need to await resp.text()?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

In the following code example for Python async, why is .text() awaited?

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get('http://httpbin.org/get') as resp:
        return await resp.text()
```

It seems like getting the text from the response would be instantaneous and wouldn't be blocking.

Comment: You should never assume the response is instantaneous. Think about it, what is going to be faster: sending the request, receiving the response, retuning the function response OR sending the request, returning the function response? Not taking that middle step is always going to outrun taking that middle step. There isn't an inherent expectation by the code that sending the request means waiting (even for just a microsecond) for a response. It has already moved on to the next step before that response comes back. That's the point of `await`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the text needs to wait for the entire response to be downloaded, which may take time for large responses or on slow networks.

Comment: Okay thanks. I thought since it checked the status code that it had already downloaded the response in full

Comment: you mean actually when we transporting the HTTP content, we get the HTTP header first and then we start to download the body? Not downloading the whole thing in one piece? I know in transport layer, we do download content package by package, but I think we cannot unpack the package until we get all the packages of one HTTP response.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for aiohttp, the [async text()](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/dce10a5ac7e4fe2e971d045d8aea5196f29a957c/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py#L960) function calls an [async read()](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/dce10a5ac7e4fe2e971d045d8aea5196f29a957c/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py#L924) function. In that, it appears to be awaiting the full response before returning. This can be useful for large payloads that take time to return.